# im trying to convert C code to MIPS program

Tags: assembly, mips

```
int s3[] = {3,5,7,5,0};
int x = 5
int c = 0
while(s3[0] != 0){
if(s3[i] == x){
c += 1; 
s3 += 1;
```

}

im trying to convert this C code into mips program assembly

Comment: `s3 += 1;` isn't even valid C for `int s3[] = ...;`.  But I think you're trying to count matches for a given `x` in an implicit-length array.  See [Code using RISC-V a program that gives the largest value in a sequence](//stackoverflow.com/q/60022937) for a loop over an implicit-length array with a slightly different condition for conditionally doing one instruction.  (RISC-V has different register names, but otherwise pretty similar to MIPS).

Comment: And of course you could just use a compiler to convert C to asm; that's literally their purpose.

Comment: Does this C code work??  If not, don't use it as a starting point for your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments. Your C code is not valid. But assuming you want to count the number of 5's in your array this would do the job:

```
.data
s3: .word 3,5,7,5,0

.text
.globl main

main:
la $t3, s3      # load adress of s3 into $t3
li $t4, 5       # load x=5 in $t4
li $t5, 0       # load c=0 in $t5
li $t6, 0       # $t6 will be list index i starting with 0  

while:
add $t7, $t6, $t3   # get adress of s3[i]
lw $t8, 0($t7)      # load word from s3[i]
beq $t8, $t1, exit  # if s3[i] == 0 break

bne $t8, $t4, if    # if s3[i] != x jump to if:
addi $t5, $t5, 1    # increment counter
if:

addi $t6, $t6, 4    # increment list index
j while
exit:
```

Assuming this is as your correct C-Code:

```
int s3[] = {3,5,7,5,0};
int x = 5;
int c = 0;
int i = 0;
while(s3[i] != 0){

  if(s3[i] == x){
    c ++; 
  }

i++;
}
```